# Cannot run Node.js application because: 'Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, passport.js

I'm doing the following tutorial:

https://www.raymondcamden.com/2017/02/08/using-social-login-with-passport-and-node/

Then, I have been creating this project (I'm using `Windows 10`):

```
> mkdir stackoverflow-question
> cd stackoverflow-question
> git clone https://github.com/napolev/stackoverflow-question.git .
> npm install
> gulp start-mongod
> Ctrl+C
> gulp run
```

But when opening the website on the browser by going to: http://localhost:4000/

I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\views"
    at EventEmitter.render (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:971:7)
    at D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\app.js:153:9
    at Layer.handle_error (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at IncomingMessage.next (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at done (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:966:25)
    at EventEmitter.render (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:582:14)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:971:7)
    at D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\app.js:127:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at isLoggedIn (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\app.js:123:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\stackoverflow-question\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

This is the the source code of the file: `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var user = require('./models/user');
var credentials = require('./credentials.json');
var passport = require('passport');
var TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var CookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var ExpressSession = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: credentials.facebook.app_id,
    clientSecret: credentials.facebook.app_secret,
    callbackURL: credentials.facebook.callback,
    profileFields:['id','displayName','emails']
    }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log(profile);
        var me = new user({
            email:profile.emails[0].value,
            name:profile.displayName
        });

        /* save if new */
        user.findOne({email:me.email}, function(err, u) {
            if(!u) {
                me.save(function(err, me) {
                    if(err) return done(err);
                    done(null,me);
                });
            } else {
                console.log(u);
                done(null, u);
            }
        });
  }
));

passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: credentials.twitter.consumer_key,
    consumerSecret: credentials.twitter.consumer_secret,
    callbackURL: credentials.twitter.callback,
    includeEmail:true
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {

        var me = new user({
            email:profile.emails[0].value,
            name:profile.displayName
        });

        /* save if new */
        user.findOne({email:me.email}, function(err, u) {
            if(!u) {
                me.save(function(err, me) {
                    if(err) return done(err);
                    done(null,me);
                });
            } else {
                console.log(u);
                done(null, u);
            }
        });

  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log(user);
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    user.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

var app = express();
app.use(CookieParser(credentials.cookieSecret));
app.use(ExpressSession({
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:false,
    secret:credentials.cookieSecret
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
    defaultLayout:'main'
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

var opts = {
    server: {
        socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1 }
    }
};

switch(app.get('env')) {
    case 'development':
        mongoose.connect(credentials.mongo.development.connectionString, opts);
        break;
    case 'production':
        mongoose.connect(credentials.mongo.production.connectionString, opts);
        break;
    default:
        throw new error('Unknown execution environment: ', app.get('env'));
}

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    req.loggedIn = !!req.user;
    next();
}

app.get('/', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        title:'Welcome to Fool',
        loggedIn:req.loggedIn
    });
});

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope:"email"}));
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', 
{ successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }));

app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter', {scope:['include_email=true']}));
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', passport.authenticate('twitter', 
  { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }));

app.get('/login', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    if(req.loggedIn) res.redirect('/');
    console.log(req.loggedIn);
    res.render('login', {
        title:'Login/Registration'
    });
});

// 500 error handler (middleware)
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500);
    res.render('error');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express running on http://localhost:' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Any idea on how to make this code (from the tutorial above) works?

For now I need to solve the error above.

Comment: Where are you setting the view directory as in  `app.set('views', somePath);`.

Comment: I didn't see a similar sentence to that on the tutorial I referenced on my post. Do you have any suitable example?. I'm just trying make this tutorial works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be because the repository you got the code from does not contain any HTML files/templates and does not register any directory from which the templates should be loaded.

Further, if you look here in the repository that you cloned from: https://github.com/napolev/stackoverflow-question, you will see that your same error is filed as a bug on that repository.

So, perhaps it's not a ready-to-run server in that regard.  Usually, you would have a `views` sub-directory and then use something like:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "views"));
```

to register its location.  And, then you'd have your templates in that directory.